# Click Button in other Form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a little program coded in C#.
I have different forms.

If I click on a button in Form1 a button in Form2 should be clicked.

Form1 Method, Class A:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click button2_Click();
}
```

Form2 Method, Class B

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Form1` needs a reference to the second form, probably when you create it. Then, once you have a reference to it, you can later simply write `form1.button2.Click()`

Comment: Also possible by using event and delegates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`Form1` implementation:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // You have to find if Form2 instance is opened
    Form2 form2 = Application.OpenForms
      .OfType<Form2>()
      .FirstOrDefault(); 

    if (null != form2)
      form2.ClickMyButton();
  }
```

`Form2` implementation:

```
  public void ClickMyButton() {
    //TODO move relevant code here from button2_Click
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ClickMyButton();
  }
```